# I facing issue while using compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+' this library to crop the image

Tags: android

Unable to find explicit activity class `{ad97.com.ocruse/com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity};` have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 4):

> Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {ad97.com.ocruse/com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity};

You should add **CropImageActivity** into your **`AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
<activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
  android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/>
```

After that,

1. **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Read [**`Android Image Cropper`**](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)

Answer (score 1):

To use dependency and Sync.

```
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
```

or

```
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.1'
```

or

```
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare CropImageActivity in Manifest file

Something like that

```
<application
android:name=".MyApplication">
<activity
android:name="ActivityName"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file add this code

```
<activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

jcenter()

in the gradle repositories

instead of using

mavenCentral() repositories